# Локализация вывода на Русский в c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, консоль, локализация

Привет!

Хочу показать решение наболевшей проблемы.

Вот так НЕ РАБОТАЕТ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //setlocale(0,"");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout<<name;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот так работает :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout<<name;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Сильно не критикуйте, хотел как лучше!

И я знаю что здесь задают вопросы. Просто многие ищут ответ на этот вопрос.
Спасибо за понимание :)

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); должно работать